# Realizar UPDATE a una columna

Tags: php, html, mysql

Mi FORM

```
<form action="submits/submit_ocupacion.php" method="POST">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="user_user">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="user_ocupacion">
  <button type="submit" name="ocupacion_submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
  Dar Ocupación
  </button>
</form>
```

mi app

```
<?php
include "cn.php";

$user_user_user = $_POST["user_user"];
$ocupacion = $_POST["user_ocupacion"];


$insertar = ("UPDATE users SET ocupacion = ('$ocupacion') WHERE username = ('$user_user_user')");
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);

if (!$resultado) {
    echo 'Error we';
} else {
echo 'Esta bn loco';
}

?>
```

Mi Conect

```
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mipass", "midb");
if (!$conexion) {
    echo 'ERROR';
}
else {
    echo 'Conectado';
}
?>
```

Bien el error comienza, cuando ejecuto el submit mediante el boton Me aparece que la coneccion esta lista, y tambien me aparece que resultado si se logro, pero pues no pasa nada, no modifica ningun valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta agregar el name a los inputs pues no le estan llegando los valores que escribes, debería quedar así:

Pues PHP para poder leer los valores que quieres manipular, va a buscar leer los valores que esten en el atributo name y tu no los pusiste

```
<form action="submits/submit_ocupacion.php" method="POST">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="user_user">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="user_ocupacion">
  <button type="submit" name="ocupacion_submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
  Dar Ocupación
  </button>
</form>
```

Por otro lado así tu código es inseguro, deberías usar sentencias preparadas, mira este ejemplo:

> Ojo yo puse una variable llamada $conexion, pero tu debes usar el
>   nombre de la variable que hayas declarado para almacenar tu conexion

La ss que coloque entre comillas ayuda a identificar que los valores que van a ingresar son de tipo cadena de texto

```
$user_user_user = $_POST["user_user"];
$ocupacion = $_POST["user_ocupacion"];
$insertar = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE users SET ocupacion = ? WHERE username = ?");
$insertar->bindParam("ss", $ocupacion, $user_user_user);
$insertar->execute();
```

Aquí te anexo los tipos de datos que puedes pasar al momento de hacer bindParam()

1. i   la variable es de tipo entero
2. d   la variable es de tipo double
3. s   la variable es de tipo string
4. b   la variable es un blob y se envía en paquetes

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar una name a tus input, para recibir los datos por un POST se hace atraves de ese atributo, el id lo usos para ponerle javascripts.

Dar Ocupación